# Outlook Add-In Actionable Message "Action.InvokeAddInCommand" no modal in OWA

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

I am developing an Actionable Message that allows a user to download an Add-In in one click. This AM works great on Outlook Desktop and I get prompted with a modal with the following information and the Add-In downloads.

> [image]

If the Add-In is installed the AM opens the Add-In, which is perfect.

**However when I use OWA it does not install the Add-In**, it only opens the Add-In if it is already installed. I get no pop up/modal. I have all these allowed on chrome and have tried different browsers etc.

Thanks in advance! Here is my Payload:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Invoking an add-in command from an Actionable Message card",
            "size": "large"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
        "type": "Action.InvokeAddInCommand",
        "title": "Install",
        "addInId": "private",
        "desktopCommandId": "private",
        "isPrimary": true
       }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of June 25th 2020, this is a Microsoft bug and the AM team is working on it.